# vue3 chart-js showing previous data on hover

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, vuejs2, vuejs3

**vue3 chart-js showing previous data on hover.**

I updated my chart data filed using API data but after updating the chat data, chart is showing previous API data on hover
i also tried using `distory()`

here are my codes

```
 methods: {
    barChart() {
      var Chart = require("chart.js");
      let options = new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-grouped"), {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
          labels: this.llabels,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "पुरुष जनसंख्या",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 143, 251, 0.8)",
              data: this.mdata,
            },
            {
              label: "महिला जनसंख्या",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 227, 150, 0.8)",
             data: this.Fdata,
             },
            {
              label: "पअन्य जनसंख्या",
              backgroundColor: "rgb(254, 176, 25,0.8)",
              data: this.Odata,
            },
          ],
        },
      });
      if (!this.chart) {
        this.chart = options;
      } else {
        this.chart.options = options;
        this.chart.update();
      }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `this.chart.options = options;`, use `this.chart.options = options.options;`

The variable options is holding your chart, not only the options.

A better approach would be to only create the chart on the first run of that method (=> place the `new Chart` inside the `if`)